# Why does backup fail with permission denied (in /var/backups)?

Tags: permissions, backup, duplicity

My backup fails and shows this message:

> Permission denied when trying to create
> '/var/backups/duplicity-full.20140907T165614Z.vol1.difftar.gpg'

How do I remedy this?

Comment: What are you using to backup?

Comment: @Lucio Given the error message, presumably Duplicity is being used.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the output of `ls -ld /var/backups`.

Answer (score 2):

Try change your backup location to your user folder `/home/[username]/backup`. Your existing user account might not have permission accessing the `/var/backups`. Otherwise, you can use `chown` and `chmod` command to make `/var/backups` folder accessible by your account.